# No display output from the computer

Tags: display, hardware-failure

I'm not that good with hardware and I'm having problem with newly assembled PC, I have two monitors connected to asus g970 graphics card on my computer.

Computer when switched on, all lights are lit up, fans spins up and such seems like working normally. But my both displays shows no input. Motherboard has in built display, tried connecting one monitor to it after removing the graphics card, same thing, no display.

Any help will be much appreciated. Since there is absolutely no display, fiddling with bios is also not possible.

Basically I'd like to know if any parts are defective and identify it. Wondering if cables are the problem but both of them going rougue at the same time seems bit unlikely amd don't have a spare lying around to test. One of the cable is dvi and other hdmi. I tried hdmi cable with on board output.

Answer (score 3):

If your monitor has multiple inputs, ensure its currently on the currect input. I've occasionally seen monitors that didn't auto switch to the correct input and had to be manually switched.

You'd also want to verify that the monitors are good by connecting them to another working computer.

Does the computer beep at all when you start it? A common problem that causes absolutely no display is memory or cpu not installed correctly.

Comment: Also you need to note whether your display say "No input signal" or not. If there is no input signal - the correct input is not selected or cabling is not good. If it doesn't show such message but only a blank screen - then there is a connection between the graphics card and a monitor, but the signal itself is not proper or graphics card doesn't output any image.